# How to avoid some characters in encryption key?

Tags: c#, encryption

I have two methods, one encrypts and the other one decrypts:

**Encrypt Method**

```
public static string Encrypt(string EncryptionMessage)
    {
        string Encrypted = string.Empty;
        string EncryptionKey = "0123456789";
        byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(EncryptionMessage);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms,   encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                Encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }

        return Encrypted;
    }
```

**Decrypt Method**

```
public static string Decrypt(string cipherText)
    {
        string Decrypted = string.Empty;
        string EncryptionKey = "0123456789";

        byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                Decrypted = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }

        return Decrypted;
    }
```

The encrypted key returns always the following characters: `\` and `/`.
I want to avoid the encrypted key returning the characters `\` and `/`.

Any help?

PS: The language is C#, i tagged it already , i am seeing c# but others are seeing another language. i tagged C# and encryption

Comment: Which language is this? It's not C, for sure. C# perhaps?

Comment: This showed in my search `C` , but this is more likely `C#` or `C++` please mark it with the correct language, so the `C#` people will come here to help you out.

Comment: Intriguing: I assumed it was Java...I agree it isn't C, but it isn't C++ either: the `using` clause is wrong for C++.

Comment: Well, we `C` developers can't even recognize the language, how could we help...

Comment: @Djama: please fix the language tag. Also, you encrypt _with_ the key; you don't encrypt the key as such. Is your concern that the key generated from the passphrase contains the verboten characters, or is it that the encrypted text (ciphertext) contains the verboten characters?  If your concern is that the encrypted text contains those characters, then you will have to encode the output to avoid them. You need to consider whether you can handle null bytes, newlines, form feeds, etc in the encrypted text.  It is best to treat the output as binary soup and not fret about any special characters.

Comment: this isn't Java; this is probably C#

Comment: The language tag is C#, i said it already , i am seeing c# but others are seeing another language. i tagged C# and encryption

Answer (score 2):

Conventional base-64 uses the character `/` in its encoding. There are variants that use a different character for that value (the 6-bit value 63), like `-` or `+`. Use one of those instead. I don't know if there's a C# API that allows you to encode with a variant directly, but you could replace `/` characters with `-` after encoding, and then switch them back before decoding.

Comment: That option is fine but i don't want to switch the characters, because it i replace it with `#` for instance after the encoding, when i want to decode it, it will replace all the `#` in the encoding string by `/` that will change the coding.